# Value Accumulating doesn't work in .css() if elem has transition property (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I'm trying to accumulate the value on a specific variable whenever I swipe the screen every time.

But the issue is, in jQuery, accumulating doesn't work with `.css` method when if the `element` has a `transition` property.

Check it out the difference:

[image]
[image]

My expectation is increasing/decreasing the `left` value 4% every 1 second. Accumulating a specific value every single time. (4%, 8%, 12% ...) (-4%, -8%, -12% ...)

I know there is an option to use `.animate()` method but as far as I know, using the `.animate()` method is way harder and complicating to give the `transition` on the target. I want to solve this issue without using the `.animate()` method as possible as I can.

Are there any ways to accumulate the value using `.css` while the element has the `transition`?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/pmGvVm) & Snippets:

```js
'use strict';
(function($, window, undefined) {

  class Slider {
    constructor(elem) {
      this.elem = elem;
      this.myFrame = this.elem.find('.inline-grid');
      this.delay(this.action);
    }
    delay(callback) {
      let binding = callback.bind(this);
      setTimeout(binding, 400);
    }
    action() {
      console.log(`waiting 400ms`);
      setInterval(() => {
        this.myFrame.css({left: '-=' + 4 + '%'})
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  $.fn.getNewSlider = function(options) {
    return this.each(() => {
      const target = $(this);
      const define = new Slider(target, options);
    })
  }

}(jQuery));

$('#element').getNewSlider();
```

```css
#element{
  position : relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inline-grid {
  position: relative;
  left : 1%;
}
.transition {
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(.93,.01,.1,.98);
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <!-- Accumulating stops when I add the transition to the class -->
  <div class="inline-grid transition">
    Bazil Leaves
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the element to smoothly slide out of the view to the left with a css transition. To do this, you don't need to worry about frames, just set the total transition time in the css transition property, and then use javascript to simply add a class that defines the end result (i.e. `.end`) after page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#element .inline-grid.transition').addClass('end');
});
```

```css
#element {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inline-grid {
  position: relative;
  left: 1%;
}

.transition.end {
  left: -100%;
}

.transition {
  transition: all 8s cubic-bezier(.93, .01, .1, .98);
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <!-- Accumulating stops when I add the transition to the class -->
  <div class="inline-grid transition">
    Bazil Leaves
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe I need to fix my question for more clearer. I want to increase or decrease left value every 1 second. Accumulating the left value (4%, 8%, 12%, 16% ...) is what I need.